# Fade in div after scrolling

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to fadein/fadeout a div depending on the amount of px scrolled by the user. Here is the existing jquery I have. I can toggle its view but i'd like to fade that toggle. What is the correct method here?

```
$("#subOverlay").hide();

$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    $("#subOverlay").toggle($(this).scrollTop() > 520);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be done as follows:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 520) {
        $("#subOverlay").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#subOverlay").stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZHkY8/

Comment: this solution is almost perfect for me. i'm using it to fade in a sticky menu on a one-page website. my only issue is that we can see the menu appear and fade when loading the page. is there a way to hide it and avoid seeing the menu appear and fade out? see here: http://dev.manifold.ws/retail28/

Comment: nevermind, i just hid my menu with css display:none; it did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 520) {
        $("#subOverlay").stop().fadeOut();
     } else {
        $("#subOverlay").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

^^ Simply reverse the array :)

Answer (score 1):

I was working on something similar to Alexander's link, but needed it to fade quicker than 100% at the top of the screen.

You can adjust when the object starts fading and when it ends fading in relation to the browser size. You can also adjust the start fade opacity if you want to start it at say 0.2 instead of 0.

http://www.kevinnunn.com/fadetest/