# How to use jQuery to hide div then fade it in on document scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, hide, fade

I'm trying to use jQuery to hide a div when the page loads, but when you scroll down to a certain point it will fade in. Right now the below script will do almost that, the problem I'm having is that the div is visible at first on page load, I want to hide it... I can't seem to figure out how.

```
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 180) {
            $("#magrig").fadeIn('slow');
        }
        else {
            $("#magrig").stop().fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });
```

I've tried adding .hide() into the script, but I can't figure out how to reformat it.

I got it origonally from here: [Fade in div after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169612/fade-in-div-after-scrolling)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using plain old CSS, that will hide it on pageload :

```
#magrig {display:none}
```

Comment: I actually didn't think of using display: none, I've tried visibility: hidden and the jQuery code didn't like that, but display works perfectly... Thanks, I feel like this was a bit of a dumb question haha

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the `div` on page load, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ("#magrig").hide();
});
```

Or you can do it directly in the CSS:

```
#magrig {
    /* other CSS entries */
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I suppose I probably could have tried that one, I was spending more time trying to figure out how to put it all into one script instead. Thanks!