# Hide an element when a user scrolls a specific distance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched questions and haven't found an answer to my specific issue: how to hide an element when a user scrolls a specific distance. I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic.

What I'd like to do:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if (document has been scrolled 250px or -250px) {
        $("#box").hide();
    } 
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery to hide div then fade it in on document scroll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584666/how-to-use-jquery-to-hide-div-then-fade-it-in-on-document-scroll)

Comment: a closer duplicate would be [Hide an element when a certain amount of scrolling has occured](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6820769/584192)

Comment: there are too many _duplicates_ but if one is looking for **exact** duplicate with same variable names and code structure there might be none. And this question is ambiguous so the solutions are pointless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/yDVXY/)

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) { 
    $("#box").css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
}
});
```

Comment: `$(this).scrollTop() > -250` minimum value for `scrollTop()` is `0` and your condition is doing noting. It'll return `true` in all cases

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
         $("#box").hide();
    }
});
```